# (int) Math.Pow(10, 0) returning zero rather than one

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm attempting to reverse an integer and for some reason I receive a RunTime error saying "System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero."
Having figured out that Math.Pow returns a **double**, why doesn't the conversion to an **int** maintain the result of "1". 10 to the 0 is 1, and 1 converting to 1 should still be 1 even if you include any rounding. Anybody have a good explanation for this?

```
if (x > 0)
        {
            var i = 0;
            while (x > 0)
            {
                int endDig = x % (10 * ((int)Math.Pow(10, i)));
                myNum += endDig.ToString();
                i += 1;
            }
            int newNum = Int32.Parse(myNum);
            return newNum;
        }
```

Comment: What is the result of `Math.Pow(10, 0)`? Is it `1.0` or is it `0.99999`?

Comment: *"converting to 1 should still be 1 even if you include any rounding."* That's the problem, you aren't rounding. By casting to an `int`, you are truncating, not rounding.

Comment: Why isn't it simply rounding up if the answer is somehow not exactly 1.00?

Comment: @springathing See my most recent edit for an explanation.

Comment: A simpler way to avoid the floating-point problem, and get to the same place, is using LINQ: 
`var num = -1235237; 
var numReversed = int.Parse(String.Join("", Math.Abs(num).ToString().Reverse()));
            if (num<0) numReversed *= -1;`

Comment: `int reversedInt = int.Parse(string.Join("", inputInt.ToString().Reverse()));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason of divide by zero here is not really related to truncating result when casting `Math.Pow(x, 0)` to int. `Math.Pow(x, 0)` will always return 1, and casting it to int will give you 1. Reason is integer overflow. For example consider:

```
var pow = (int)Math.Pow(10, 10);
```

10^10 does not fit into int size, so it will overflow (multiple times), and variable `pow` will have value `-2147483648`. When you multiply that by 10, it again overflows and result is 0. At this point you get your divide by zero exception.

To avoid such bizzare results you might want to do arithmetic operations that might unexpectedly result in overflow in checked context:

```
checked {
    var pow = (int) Math.Pow(10,10); 
    // throws overflow exception so you can fix your buggy code early
}
```

Of course at that point you already realize that your algorithm to reverse number is not a good one, so refer to another answer for a better way.

Comment: I just received "System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32" for input of 1534236469 so I think you're right, what would be a solution, should I do Int64.Partse instead?

Comment: "To avoid such bizzare results..." or find a different algorithm that avoids the problem completely.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice very true, but I think author already got that his algorithm is not very good. Checked context is just to reveal the problem earlier, not really to fix anything.

Comment: The lesson is to verify one's assumptions using a debugger.

Answer (score 6):

You are encountering limitations of computer-based arithmetic. (Another answer shows the details which I were incorrect in previous versions of my answer.) To avoid these details entirely, you can divide by 10 at the end of each iteration of the loop:

```
while (x > 0)
{
    int endDig = x % 10;
    //...
    x /= 10;
}
```

Now you no longer need to worry the limits of `int` because your number will never be larger than the original input.

Comment: I'm not completely sure why I was using a string to store the reversed version but originally I think I over complicated what I needed to do for negative inputs

Comment: @springathing The string is fine. The problem is that you are encountering the inexactness of floating point numbers and truncation when casting to an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Math.Pow(10, 0) returns 1 .

[image]

I dont think that it returns 0.9999 and by casting it to int its getting truncated.

Comment: I like your thoughts, but it doesn't really answer the question...Please try to answer the actual question :)